# Cannot find module '@module/kinetic-erp-tester-e2e'/ tsconfig paths only in ubuntu

Tags: angular, typescript, ubuntu, protractor, tsconfig-paths

We have below error and it happens only in ubuntu, it seems to deal with tsconfig paths. tsconfig is updated like below. Please advise if different approach needs to be handled.

```
`"paths": {
      "@module/kinetic-e2e": ["dist/kinetic-e2e"],
      "@module/kinetic-erp-tester-e2e": ["dist/kinetic-erp-tester-e2e"]
    }`
```

> [14:02:30] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
> [14:02:30] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
> [14:02:36] E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
> projects/metafx/metafx-harness-e2e/src/common/helper.ts(2,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@module/kinetic-erp-tester-e2e' or its corresponding type declarations.